# Custom validation in Angular4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

In my page I am having a simple form group. in which I have to write a custom validation for a name.

```
this.searchForm = this._formBuilder.group({

        profileName: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
        TypeId: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
        tempRange: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
        region: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
        quarter1: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
        quarter2: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required]))

    }, {
            validator: this.customValidator// your validation method
        });
```

I have put the custom validation in a method **this.customValidator** .

One of my validation is to check duplicate check for profileName.

I am having issue on getting other method (where validation logic resides) in the same type script class from the validation method, when I am calling that method (which is not static or a function) I am getting an error as (on pressing <kbd>f12</kbd>)

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
>   this.validateProfileName is not a function... '.

Is there any way to call the particular method, or I need to implement all the logic in side the validation method it self.

Also how can I show the validation error message from there in the same style as the required field validation error message.

My validation method

```
customValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
    debugger;
    let profileName = control.get('profileName').value;
    let retgionCode = control.get('regionCode').value;
    let forcastType = control.get('forecastTypeId');
    var status = this.validateProfileName(retgionCode, profileName);

    if (!status)
    control.get("profileName").setErrors({ 'invalidProfileName': true });

    return null;
}
```

Comment: No one can know what the error is in your code if you don't show us your code ;)

Comment: I have added the method and the exact error. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `this`. As you are having it now, you are loosing the scope of `this`. Inside your custom validator, `this` is not pointing to your component scope, but the function scope. And there is no `validateProfileName` in the scope of the function, so Angular is giving you the correct error.

To preserve the context of `this`, bind it:

```
validator: this.customValidator.bind(this)
```

Now you have access to the scope outside of the custom validator.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comment, please confirm where i need to call the binding ? is it the same place where i am calling the validator ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing more work than you need to do, and you aren't calling a function in your custom validator anyways. This is what you want:

```
this.searchForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    profileName: ['', Validators.required],
    TypeId: ['', Validators.required],
    tempRange: ['', Validators.required],
    region: ['', Validators.required],
    quarter1: ['', Validators.required],
    quarter2: ['', Validators.required]
}, { validator: this.customValidator() });
```

Then in your validation function, you need to do this:

```
customValidator() {
    debugger;
    let profileName = this.searchForm.get('profileName').value;
    let retgionCode = this.searchForm.get('regionCode').value;
    let forcastType = this.searchForm.get('forecastTypeId');
    let status = this.validateProfileName(retgionCode, profileName);

    if (!status) {
        this.searchForm.get("profileName").setErrors({ 'invalidProfileName': true });
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but i cannot call the validation method as you suggested, I have updated my post adding the validation method too. in which i have to give a parameter abstract control and the method is hitting even without  "()" in the call.

Comment: You will throw an error 100% of the time if you call a function that is expecting a parameter, and you don't supply one. Sure you can call your function without the (), but in this case you need to, but your function is requiring an AbstractControl.

Comment: if i am commenting out the "var status = this.validateProfileName(retgionCode, profileName);" from the method, the debugger is hitting without any error and i am getting the particular AbstractControl from where the validation is called. I am also getting the Profile Name and Region Code while debugging.

Comment: control is going to be undefined unless you pass something into the customValidation function. Your code is incomplete. I will update my post to what you want.